# How do I source a file based on a shell command in .tmux.conf?

Tags: shell, tmux

I'm trying to do something like

`if-shell "[[ -r $(python -m site --user-site)/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf ]]" 'source "$(python -m site --user-site)/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf"'`
, 
but it doesn't quite work. I don't want to hard code the path because it might be different between Linux and Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the syntax:

```
if-shell shell-command tmux-command1 tmux-command2
```

you can use `$()` in the 2nd part `shell-command` as the shell will interpret this, but not in the two tmux command parts. One solution is to make the tmux command a `run-shell` that runs `tmux source-file`, i.e. replace your `'source...'` by

```
 'run-shell "tmux source-file $(python -m site --user-site)/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf"'
```